# Return is an invalid expression term "return"

Tags: c#, methods

I need to call this Stored Procedure but when I bring it into the .dbml is is being converted to resulting as ISingleResult. I am not sure how to properly call this with all of the parameters. This is my current code but I get an error when I "return result" saying "Invalid Expression term "return"" Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

```
public static int CreateNewTransferee(CreateTransferee model)
    {
        using (var db = new NJB.NJBDataContext())
        {
                var result = db.SP_AddTransferee(
                model.TransferEffectiveDate,
                model.TransfereeName,
                model.TransfereeNoticeAddressLine1,
                model.TransfereeNoticeAddressLine2,
                model.TransfereeNoticeCity,
                model.TransfereeNoticeState,
                model.TransfereeNoticeZip,
                model.TransfereeNoticePhone,
                model.TransfereePaymentAddressLine1,
                model.TransfereePaymentAddressLine2,
                model.TransfereePaymentCity,
                model.TransfereePaymentState,
                model.TransfereePaymentZip,
                model.TransfereePaymentPhone,

            return (int) result.ReturnValue;
        }
    }
```

Update: Here is the SP:

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_AddTransferee] 
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@TransferEffectiveDate datetime,
@TransfereeName varchar(50),
@TransfereeNoticeAddressLine1 varchar(50),
@TransfereeNoticeAddressLine2 varchar(50),
@TransfereeNoticeCity varchar(50),
@TransfereeNoticeState varchar(2),
@TransfereeNoticeZip varchar(12),
@TransfereeNoticePhone varchar(50),
@TransfereePaymentAddressLine1 varchar(50),
@TransfereePaymentAddressLine2 varchar(50),
@TransfereePaymentCity varchar(50),
@TransfereePaymentState varchar(50),
@TransfereePaymentZip varchar(50),
@TransfereePaymentPhone varchar(50)

AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Insert statements for procedure here
INSERT INTO TransfereeList
VALUES (@TransferEffectiveDate, @TransfereeName, @TransfereeNoticeAddressLine1, @TransfereeNoticeAddressLine2,
    @TransfereeNoticeCity, @TransfereeNoticeState, @TransfereeNoticeZip, @TransfereeNoticePhone, 
    @TransfereePaymentAddressLine1, @TransfereePaymentAddressLine2, 
    @TransfereePaymentCity, @TransfereePaymentState, @TransfereePaymentZip, @TransfereePaymentPhone);

SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();
```

END

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing a close paren and semicolon.

```
public static int CreateNewTransferee(CreateTransferee model)
{
    using (var db = new NJB.NJBDataContext())
    {
        var result = db.SP_AddTransferee(
            model.TransferEffectiveDate,
            model.TransfereeName,
            model.TransfereeNoticeAddressLine1,
            model.TransfereeNoticeAddressLine2,
            model.TransfereeNoticeCity,
            model.TransfereeNoticeState,
            model.TransfereeNoticeZip,
            model.TransfereeNoticePhone,
            model.TransfereePaymentAddressLine1,
            model.TransfereePaymentAddressLine2,
            model.TransfereePaymentCity,
            model.TransfereePaymentState,
            model.TransfereePaymentZip,
            model.TransfereePaymentPhone);
        //                              ^^ right here

        return (int) result.ReturnValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, been looking at a screen for too long. Thanks a lot haha, always miss the small things.

Comment: @Nick_M: I had assumed that was just a typo when copying the code. You're still just casting the return value to `int` though - does that really work for you?

Comment: @JonSkeet well, I am looking to simply return the int that the SP is providing me with after taking the parameters. It is being used to insert a new "transferee" into the DB. However, I am now having issues in the controller calling this method. So I may have another question up soon.

Answer (score 0):

You  can try  [result.First()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb908080%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) to get the integer.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be incomplete...??? if correct then do like this..

```
public static int CreateNewTransferee(CreateTransferee model)
    {
        var result;
        using (var db = new NJB.NJBDataContext())
        {
                result = db.SP_AddTransferee(
                model.TransferEffectiveDate,
                model.TransfereeName,
                model.TransfereeNoticeAddressLine1,
                model.TransfereeNoticeAddressLine2,
                model.TransfereeNoticeCity,
                model.TransfereeNoticeState,
                model.TransfereeNoticeZip,
                model.TransfereeNoticePhone,
                model.TransfereePaymentAddressLine1,
                model.TransfereePaymentAddressLine2,
                model.TransfereePaymentCity,
                model.TransfereePaymentState,
                model.TransfereePaymentZip,
                model.TransfereePaymentPhone,    

        }
         return result;
    }
```

Comment: Not incomplete, just declared the variable and defined it at the same time. declaring it where you did causes an error:"implicitly-typed local variables must be initialized"